# Is it possible to make card numbers in Trello unique across an organisation?

Tags: trello

We have a couple of boards (*Active* and *Backlog*) and have noticed when you move a card from one board to another the card number changes. We refer to items by card number and it would be really handy if the card numbers were unique for the organisation, regardless of the board.

It looks as though the link to the card stays the same so we may need to start using that as a reference. There are 2 drawbacks:

1. We use the Chrome extension that exposes the card number, we wouldn't be able to do that any more and we'd have to drill into the card to get to the details
2. We quote the card number on our support tickets for reference, we wouldn't necessarily want the customers seeing that link and it makes it less user friendly

Is there a setting we can change? I can't find one.

Comment: I have edited your question slightly, removing the "Thank you", which we don't use here. Welcome to [webapps.se]!

Comment: Thanks @VidarS.Ramdal, not sure if it's the done thing to thank you in a comment! I'll leave it out of questions in future

Comment: Quick cliarifiation: when I reference a card in a comment using the `#1` format, my #1 card is always my #1 card regardless of what board it is in (it's an old, long archived card since it was my first). Are you referring to that number or a different number I'm not familiar with? Also, are you moving cards from one team/organization to another or just from one board to another within the same team/organization?

Comment: I'm moving cards between boards in the same organisation, so if I refer to #1 in our backlog board it gets a different number when I move it to the Active board (the unique trello URL stays the same)